# нужна помощь по PyTelegramBot

Tags: python, telebot

Пытаюсь учить PyTelegramBot и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
сделал боту функцию решения примеров  с помощью Eval
у бота есть заготовленный ответ на не обрабатываемые Слова\символы
но после добавления функции с решением примеров бот  воспринимает неизвестные ему символы как переменные(насколько я понял)
Пишу в чат например "и"
в консоле выдает ошибку (name "и" is not dedined)

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def get_text_messages(message):

        if message.text == 'Привет':
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,("Привет"))

        elif "-" or "+" or "*" or "/" in message.text:
            total = eval(message.text)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,(f"Ответ = {total}"))

        else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,("Я тебя не понимаю"))
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    
def get_text_messages(message):
    
    if message.text == 'Привет':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Привет")
    
    elif "-" in message.text or "+" in message.text or "*" in message.text or "/" in message.text:
        total = eval(message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,f"Ответ = {total}")
    
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Я тебя не понимаю")
```

Как бы странно не выглядело, но зато вашей ошибки не будет

Данный код будет проверять, есть ли в message.text текст /,*,-,+

Я бы ещё порекомендовал сделать так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    
    if message.text == 'Привет':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Привет")
    
    elif "-" in message.text or "+" in message.text or "*" in message.text or "/" in message.text :
        try:
            total = eval(message.text)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,f"Ответ = {total}")
        except SyntaxError:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Что?")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,"Я тебя не понимаю"))
```

Вот этот код уже будет избегать ошибки, если вы просто введёте "-" ну или другое, то он ответит "Что?" вы можете сделать как хотите

Comment: Помог только 1 способ, Со вторым и третьим та же ошибка осталась. Спасибо
Если есть возможность хотелось бы узнать из за чего происходит данная проблема заранее спасибо

Comment: Ну тут можно сказать, что когда вы делаете так ( "-" or "+" or "*" or "/" in message.text ) то он по логике должен работать так:
Если в message.text есть - или + или т.д. то тогда он выдаёт True, а так, на самом деле он работает так, что он делает его как чтоль переменную, потому что если сделать так:
a = "/" or "-" in "abc"
b = "/" in "abc"
c = "/" in "ab/"
abc = "/" in "abc" or "ab/"
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(abc)
то вывод будет таким
/
False
True
ab/
Из этого делаем вывод, что ему обязательно нужно указывать где именно, в любом случае я возможно не так говорю,я не эксп

Comment: Я кстати понял почему в остальных не работает, потому-что я сделал так: message.text in "-" or "+" or "*" or "/", а нужно было как в первом примере, вот так: "-" in message.text or "+" in message.text or "*" in message.text or "/" in message.text

Но в любом случае, надеюсь будет человек которые ответит так, как это реально работает и объяснит как на самом деле работает, вот так

Answer (score 0):

Чуть более элегантным решением будет:

```
special_symbols = ['+', '-', '/', '/'] 

if message.text == 'Привет':
   
    ... 

else:

    for symbol in special_symbols:

        if symbol in message.text:

            ... 
            #вычисляем выражение
            break

    else:

        ... 
        #другое действие
```

Если что, else тут не ошибка табуляции - он здесь именно для цикла `for`. Если break не будет использован, то будет выполнено то, что под `else`